# Grpc multiple clients with their own stream requests invoking a server grpc method fail if > 1 client is used

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I create 2 client to invoke 2 different servers with stream requests.

```
// First client call

using var httpClient1 = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
using var channel1 = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:4555", new GrpcChannelOptions {HttpClient = httpClient1});
var grpcClient1 = new MyGrpc.GrpcClient(channel1);

// Invoked grpcClient1 method

// Second client call

using var httpClient2 = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
using var channel2 = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:5555", new GrpcChannelOptions {HttpClient = httpClient2});
var grpcClient2 = new MyGrpc.GrpcClient(channel2);

// Invoked grpcClient2 method
```

I expected to see results from 2 clients.
Instead I saw that 1 client worked successfully, the 2 client fails

> Status(StatusCode=Internal, Detail="")

the first one is invoked successfully.
The second one fails with an exception "Error starting gRPC call: The SSL connection couldn't be established"

If I comment the first call, invocation of the second call is performed successfully.
If I uncomment the first call, invocation of the second call fails.

Troubleshooting didn't help, none of debug parameters showed up during debugging.

Comment: what is `httpClientHandler` in your sample ?

Comment: this has been filed as https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/722 - let's continue the discussion there.